# 'Search on Yammer' link in search center refiners

Tags: search, search-results, display-template, refiner, refinement-panel

I have a heavily branded site I'm working on and can't find where the "Search on Yammer" link is being populated from. It appears within the search refiner/filter web part in the left column but none of the display templates reference this.

I'd like to be able to customize the link, placement on the page, etc. without resorting to jQuery to move elements around the page.

[image: Screenshot]

And the markup coming through looks like this. The refiners themselves come through a series of display templates but the Yammer link is nowhere that I can see in any of them.

```
<div webpartid="f09e98eb-6dc3-4a9b-8dbf-65d0fbc7b7c3" haspers="false" id="WebPartWPQ4" width="100%" class="ms-WPBody " allowdelete="false" style="">
    <div class="ms-ref-ctrl">
        <div class="ms-ref-refiner">
            <div id="Container">
                <h2 class="ms-displayInline">
                    <a class="ms-ref-name ms-displayInlineBlock ms-srchnav-link-selected ms-link" href="javascript:void(window.open(
                    'https://www.yammer.com/search?trk_event=o365_search&amp;search='+
                    encodeURIComponent(Srch.ScriptApplicationManager.get_current().queryGroups.
                    Default.dataProvider.get_currentQueryState().k),'_blank'));" title="Open a new tab to search for this on Yammer">Search on Yammer</a>
                </h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div componentid="ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_f09e98eb_6dc3_4a9b_8dbf_65d0fbc7b7c3_csr" id="ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_f09e98eb_6dc3_4a9b_8dbf_65d0fbc7b7c3_csr">        
    ... refiners populated through display templates ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I used css to hide it, that seemed to work okay but I am sure there are better solutions out there.

```
h2.ms-displayInline a.ms-ref-name{ display:none;}
```

Best of luck.