# How do I remove Yammer in SharePoint 2013 inside search ?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, yammer, yammer-embed

[image]

I would like to know I can remove yammer appearing in SP search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already another post with the same question. You can hide "Search on Yammer" by css. ['Search on Yammer' link in search center refiners](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/178361/search-on-yammer-link-in-search-center-refiners)